# Spring boot retry for AWS exceptions

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot

I am trying to do copy between different bucket and if there is any exception occurs while copying or reading objects, method should do retry. I am using spring boot, java, aws sdk 1.11.x. can you please guide me.

```
@Async("asyncCopyS3Executor")
@Retryable(value = { AmazonCloudFrontException.class,
        AmazonServiceException.class }, maxAttempts = 3, backoff =   Backoff(delay = 2000, multiplier = 2, maxDelay = 9000))
public void copyS3Content(){
//copying file between s3
// invalidating CF for this
}

@Recover
private void recoverAmazonCloudFrontException(AmazonCloudFrontException exception) {
    LOG.info("AmazonCloudFrontException during copyS3Content: {}",  exception.getMessage());
    //If finally operation fails, it will set flags
}

@Recover
private void recoverAmazonServiceException(AmazonServiceException exception) {
    LOG.debug("AmazonServiceException during copyS3Content: {}", exception.getMessage());
    //If finally operation fails, it will set flags
}
```

Comment: Share the code snippet

Comment: I have share the code snippet

Comment: What is the exception you’re facing?

Comment: I am using @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class) and test cases are not working

Comment: Can you check the issue in testing code ? Because use have use different way for async methods in testing Mockito